# Collection initializer that compiles but throws exceptions

Tags: c#

I was a little fast when declaring a collection initializer and ended up with something that compiles, but fails when it runs. My question is what it is I have written, and why does it compile? This test reproduces the issue:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExploratoryTests
{
    [Test, Ignore]
    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            var test = new TestClass
            {
                ListOfStrings = { "hello", "world", "!" }
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public class TestClass
    {
        public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
    }      
}
```

This will print the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
What I meant to do was to initialize ListOfStrings with  `new List<string> { "hello", "world", "!" }`. This runs fine ofcourse.

I have tried searching, but I do not know what this construct is called. I have searched some C# books with no luck. The help I seek is a name for this construct and a pointer to an explanation of what it should be used for and why this compiles.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Behind the covers, your property List<string> ListOfStrings refers  to a pointer to some memory.  When you don't initialize with the new keyword, the pointer either contains an invalid value or points to memory that hasn't been allocated (that's what the error message is trying to tell you.)  It compiles because it doesn't actually try to write to that memory location until you run the program.

Comment: @Duston, "pointers", etc. is entirely the wrong vocabulary for this since we're talking about a managed language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have here:

```
var test = new TestClass
{
    ListOfStrings = { "hello", "world", "!" }
};
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var test = new TestClass();
test.ListOfStrings.Add("hello");
test.ListOfStrings.Add("world");
test.ListOfStrings.Add("!");
```

But `ListOfStrings` is `null`.

If your class was instead defined like this, you would not get any error:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
    public TestClass()
    {
        ListOfStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are of course correct, but can you provide the reason (spec-wise) that `new TestClass { ListOfStrings = { "hello", "world", "!" } }` is different from `new TestClass { ListOfStrings = new List<string> { "hello", "world", "!" } }`?

Comment: Object initializers simply assign properties as per the example above (second block of code). Without creating a `new List<string>` the `ListOfStrings` reference is null - you can't call a method on a null reference. Don't forget the object initializers are just syntactic sugar for a bunch of operations

Comment: @Charleh, they are both "object initializers".

Comment: Yep, I didn't say anything to the contrary (my reference was to the code in the answer). Check here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers for details - specifically the "Collection Initializers" bit